# FOIA to Office of Parliamentary Counsel to gain insight to the intentions of statutory minutiae

Tags: united-kingdom, interpretation, foia

Has it ever been done to FOIR the office of parliamentary counsel to find out whether certain minute idiosyncrasies judged by courts to be nonetheless unequivocal so as to reflect intentional distinctions were in fact reflective of intention to nuanced distinctions or simply coincidental oversights?

I'm thinking of things that actual MPs may be far too busy to have awareness of in the scope and level of details of their parliamentary debates, but the lawyers actually drafting the legislations' language would have considered in detail.

As an aside would their drafting notes kind of like "code comments" in source code be recorded anywhere and would they even be subject to FOIA if so?

And if one were to do this, what impact would it have on the judicial interpretation subsequently?

Comment: Re "code comments": most bills/acts are accompanied by Explanatory Notes which describe in detail the background and intention of the legislation. I don't know if these can be referred to in court.

Comment: Yeah but those are more like inline documentation /intentional multiline comments that specify a function's usage and output than ad-hoc comments that occur within a function's implementation for example.

Comment: And also similarly cursory. Like code comments they do not have the force of law themselves and arguably no direct legal effect. But I imagine they have persuasive value, but they just don't offer that much insight into minutiae that could just as easily be coincidental.

Comment: Sure - but I'd also argue that regardless of who actually wrote the original version of a bill, the official author is the Crown-in-Parliament. And your [other question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/89442/can-courts-consider-hansard-transcripts-in-interpreting-statutes) already covers whether proceedings in Parliament can be inspected in court.

Comment: Not sure i get the full thrust of your comment.

Comment: Sorry, my point is that the only officially relevant commentary is what happens as a bill passes through Parliament. What happens _before_ a bill is first presented to Parliament is regarded as irrelevant - and as described in the answer below, we're apparently not entitled to know what happens before that stage anyway, so my comment is mostly irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any such documents would be protected by parliamentary privilege. See [this primer](https://ico.org.uk/media/for-organisations/documents/1161/section_34_parliamentary_privilege.pdf) on the interaction between freedom-of-information requests and parliamentary privilege.

> [Parliamentary privilege] is a set of
> constitutional law principles, originating in the Middle Ages and
> partially codified in the 17th century onwards, which provide
> certain rights (or privileges) to allow Parliament to work
> effectively and independently, without interference from the
> monarchy, courts or other authorities.

It includes:

- "Internal papers prepared by the officials of either House
  directly relating to House or committee proceedings, eg
  briefing papers or notes of committee meetings.
- "Correspondence between members, House officials,
  ministers and government officials, where the
  correspondence directly and specifically relates to House
  or committee proceedings."